# Understunding the inherited atlas

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, problem-solving

I have to prove the following:

> Consider $M:= \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1 \}$. Prove that $M$ is a smooth manifold and that the map  $\Phi : \Bbb{R} \times (0,2\pi) \hookrightarrow M $ given by
> $$\Phi(u,v)=(\sqrt{1+u^2} \cos{(v)}, \sqrt{1+u^2} \sin{(v)}, u)$$
> is compatible with the inherited atlas of being a submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^3$ .

In order to prove that $M$ is a smooth manifold, let denote $F: \Bbb{R}^3 \hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ given by $F(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 -z^2 -1 = 0$ . Hence, $F$ is clearly smooth, $M=F^{-1}(0)$ and $\nabla _p F = (2x,2y,-2z)$, so $\nabla _p F = 0 \iff p=0 $ .

If $p=(x,y,z) \in F^{-1}(0) \Rightarrow x^2 + y^2 = z^2 + 1 \geq 1 \Rightarrow x > 0 \lor y>0 \Rightarrow p \neq 0 $ . Therefore, $0$ is a regular value of $F$ and by the Regular Value Theorem $M$ is a smoothe manifold.

For the second part I am having trouble to understund "who" is the inherited atlas in this case.

My teacher defines as follows:

> If $N$ is a smooth manifold and $M \subset N$ a smooth submanifold, an *inherited chart* of $M$ from a given chart $(U, \varphi)$ of $N$ is $(U \cap M, \varphi|_{U\cap M})$. An *inherited atlas* of $M$ is the union of the inherited charts of an atlas on $N$ .

The usual atlas of $\Bbb{R}^n$ is $\mathcal{A}_n = \{(\Bbb{R}^n, Id_{\Bbb{R}^n})\}$, so the inherited atlas of $M$ would be $\{(M, Id_M)\}$. The problem is that if this is an atlas, $M$ is open and it is not.

Did I misunderstund something? Is there another atlas that I should consider to prove the exercise?

Thank in advance :)

Comment: But $M$ **is** open in the subspace topology of $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Your definition of an inherited atlas is simply wrong: it does not yield an atlas on $M$. Check your notes again. Talk to your teacher and consult a textbook if you have any.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry, I don't understund, what do you mean?

Comment: @SammyBlack it is, but is image in the chart has to be an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^3$, and it is not since $M$ is not open in the usual topology.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I thought so, I will ask my teacher. Thanks!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez oh, you are right! thanks :)

Comment: What is the definition of a smooth submanifold? Which theorems have been proved about smooth submanifolds?

Comment: @PaulFrost If $M=(X,A)$ is a smooth manifold where $A$ is an atlas, a smooth submanifold $N \subseteq M$ is a subset such that $\forall x \in N \hspace{2mm} \exists (U,\varphi) \in A : x \in U \land \varphi(U \cap N) = \{0\}^d \times \Bbb{R}^{n-d}$ where $d, n\in \Bbb{N}$. The only theoretical results I know are: 1. $N$ is submanifold iff the inclusion is an embedding, 2. The Regular Value Theorem

Comment: What is the definition of an embedding? And what does it mean for a map to be compatible with an atlas?

Comment: @PaulFrost An embedding $f$ is a smooth homeomorphism onto its image such that for any point $x$ on its dom, any charts $(U, \varphi)$  and $(V, \psi)$ around $x$ and $f(x)$ respectively, $ D_y ( \psi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1} )$ is injective for any $y$. Two charts $(U,\varphi), (V, \psi)$ are compatible if $\psi \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is $C^\infty$. A chart is compatible with an atlas if it is compatible with each chart of the atlas.

Comment: But $\Phi$ is not a chart. It could be the inverse of a chart.

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, it is the inverse of a chart, so $\Phi ^{-1}$ is the chart. In fact I never said that $\Phi$ is a chart. Moreover, I am not asking about this in the post.

Comment: I encourage you to be precise. You ask "Prove that $\Phi$ is compatible with the inherited atlas of being a submanifold", but do not explain what compatible means in this context. In a comment you write "A chart is compatible with an atlas if it is compatible with each chart of the atlas." So what does it mean that the given $\Phi$ is compatible? Either there is separate definition (perhaps in the sense that $\Phi$ is a smoth embedding into $M$) or you need to explain somewhat more (perhaps in the sense that it is easy to show that $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism onto on open subset of $M$ so that

Comment: $\Phi^{-1}$ is a chart on $M$ and the task is to show that this chart is compatible with the inherited atlas). And add all relevant information to your question, people do not want to read comments to completely understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you write in a comment, a $d$-codimensional smooth submanifold $M$ of an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold $N$ is defined as follows:

> For each $p \in M$ there exists a (smooth) chart $(U,\varphi)$ on $N$ with $p \in U$ such that $\varphi(U \cap M) = \varphi(U) \cap \tilde{\mathbb R}^{n-d}$, where $\tilde{\mathbb R}^{n-d} = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb R^n \mid x_i = 0  \text{ for } i \le d\}$.

Let call such $(U,\varphi)$ an *admissible chart for $M$* (this is just an adhoc notation).

The map $r : \tilde{\mathbb R}^{n-d} \to \mathbb R^{n-d}, r(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_{d+1}, \ldots, x_n)$, is a homeomorphism. To each chart $(\varphi,U)$ which is admissible for $M$ we associate the *inherited chart*  $(\tilde \varphi, \tilde U)$ with
$$\tilde U = U \cap M,$$

$$\tilde \varphi : U \cap M \xrightarrow{\varphi \mid_{U \cap M}} \varphi(U) \cap \tilde{\mathbb R}^{n-d} \xrightarrow{r \mid_{\varphi(U) \cap \tilde{\mathbb R}^{n-d}}} \tilde V$$
where $\tilde V = r(\varphi(U) \cap \tilde{\mathbb R}^{n-d}) \subset \mathbb R^{n-d}$. Clearly $\tilde \varphi$ is a homeomorphism from the open subset $U \cap M$ of $M$ to the open subset $\tilde V$ of $\mathbb R^{n-d}$, thus it is (topological) chart on $M$.

It is important to understand that the image $\varphi(U \cap M) = \varphi(U) \cap \tilde{\mathbb R}^{n-d}$ is **not open in $\mathbb R^n$** (unless $d = 0$); it is the intersection of the open subset $\varphi(U)$ with the $(n-d)$-dimensional linear subspace $\tilde{\mathbb R}^{n-d}$. But this intersection is open in the subspace $\tilde{\mathbb R}^{n-d}$ of $\mathbb R^n$, and therefore it is mapped by $r$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb R^{n-d}$. In other words, the map $\varphi \mid_{U \cap M}  : U \cap M \to \varphi(U \cap M)$ cannot be a chart on $M$, we need to compose it with $r$ to get a chart on $M$.

Also observe that this construction only works for charts on $N$ which are admissible for $M$. You cannot take an arbitrary chart on $N$ and expect that it produces a chart on $M$.

By the way, let me mention that it is more usual to set $m = n-d$ and call $M$ an $m$-dimensional smooth submanifold $M$ of $N$.

The collection of all inherited charts on $M$ (based on the admissible charts on $N$) is obviously an atlas on the topological space $M$, but it remains to show that all transition functions are smooth. Once this has been done, you know that the inherited charts provide a smooth atlas on $M$, i.e. that $M$ inherits the structure of a smooth manifold from $N$.

If $M \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a submanifold (as your concrete example $M \subset \mathbb R^3$), then in general $(Id_{\mathbb R^n}, \mathbb R^n)$ will not be an admissible chart for $M$. But your atlas $\mathcal A_n$ generates the standard maximal atlas on $\mathbb R^n$ which consists of all diffeomorphisms (in the sense of multivariable calculus) between open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. Then you can take all *admissible charts for $M$* and perform the above construction. But recall that $\varphi(U \cap M)$ will not be open in $\mathbb R^n$, only relatively open in an $(n-d)$-dimensional subspace.

To solve your problem it is not expedient to try to determine explicitly all charts on $M$. This attempt would be fairly hopeless. This is why I asked for theorems about submanifolds. Also it needs  a precise definition of what it means that $\Phi$ is compatible with the inherited atlas.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer and comments. Despite, I do not see how this helps to understund the problem in my exercise. As I wrote, the inherited atlas of $M$ would be $\{ (M, Id_M) \}$, so as an atlas needs to $Id_M (M) = M$ been an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^3$, but it is not. Is there anything I am missing?